# How can I stop the browser identifying my server

Tags: server, http-headers

When I check my headers with some of the websites around, they can tell that I am using Apache.

For example -

```
Headers returned from: https://example.com

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection: Upgrade, close
Date: Mon, 24 Oct 2022 12:19:06 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
```

I am using a shared server.  **How can I stop this information *(Server:Apache)* from leaking out using htaccess or php ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using a shared server.

Then you probably can't control what is output.

It is defined by Apache directive `ServerTokens` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens)  which can't appear in `.htaccess` file, only in main configuration.

More important: what do you think you can achieve by withholding this information?

In practice, not much, because even if not there, there are various other ways to fingerprint a webserver and to know what it runs. Also, for an attacker, knowing there is PHP running on it is far more useful than knowing the underlying webserver used.